# Why is OpenSSL 1.1.1 (Linux client) sending application data before Change Cipher Spec?

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls

We use an in-house compiled OpenSSL 1.1.1i for Windows and Linux.

Our client in Windows connects succesfully with an Nginx server (which I don't know the version).

The Linux client fails with the "alert bad record mac" error.

Wireshark shows the Windows client sending "application data" **only** after it sends Change Cipher Spec.

Wireshark shows the Linux client sending "application data" **before** it sends Change Cipher Spec. (For all we know the application data doesn't come from the client application).

Soon afterwards the server sends an "application record" which fires the "bad record mac" error in the client.

So, what could cause that ? How come the library sends "application data" before "Change Cipher Spec" ? Is that even allowed ?

UPDATE

I added some more images, in case anyone would be interested.
(I don't know if it's considered bad form or spam to add many images. If that's the case I'll remove them).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried alternative clients, to rule out e.g. hardware problems or compilation-related problems? (For example, GnuTLS-based tools, or the same OpenSSL 1.1.1 provided by the distro? Or, let's say, the latest OpenSSL 1.1.1k?)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP indicates in a comment posted as an answer that bugs in their own code were the cause of this issue.

Comment: it was a bug in my code ... I think it's ok to close this question ... sorry for the inconvenience people

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at TLS version 1.3, which has a quite different handshake than that of earlier versions.

In TLS 1.3, the "ChangeCipherSpec" message is meaningless – it is only sent to satisfy some intrusion detection systems which absolutely insist on seeing one (there are systems which try to block "malformed" TLS connections).

Additionally, all handshake messages following ServerHello [are encrypted](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#page-11) in TLS 1.3, and disguised as "Application Data" messages (to pacify firewalls and IDS systems) with the actual message type being hidden inside the encrypted payload.

So the first few "Application Data" messages in your log may actually contain handshake payloads such as the encrypted "Certificate" message, rather than the actual application request.

Answer (score 1):

The "mac" in the message may pertain to the
[Message authentication code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code),
meaning in this case that the message cannot be authenticated.

I would guess that the Linux client and the Nginx server are
not using the same cipher or the same TLS version,
while the Windows software uses the correct version.

So check the versions that are actually used or installed on
both ends, or their configured parameters.